# CSS3 flexible/responsive Flip card loses back face at end of transform

Tags: css, responsive-design, css-transitions, css-transforms

Similar to a few other examples of flip cards:
[similar example 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15909208/css3-card-flip-backface-disappears-at-end-of-transform)

However the answer is normally to ensure no background is on the containing card, and specified on the front and back face of the card. however this will not work for my example, due to the fact the back face with text on it, will not occupy the same height as the picture on the front.

I have occasionally had it working correctly, but then after a refresh of the page, it returns to being broken again.

[My Code](http://jsfiddle.net/nsUZB/)

```
.flipper{
            //transform: perspective(1000px);
            transform-style: preserve-3d;
            position: relative;
            width: 100%;
            min-height: 345px;
            transition: 0.6s;
            background-color: rgb(242,245,245);
            box-shadow: 1px 2px 20px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6) inset, 1px 2px 5px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
        }
```

I have yet to start any cross-browser testing on this, but what sort of usable(non animated) support am I looking at?

I realise this is very similar to others questions, however this case should differ enough in terms of not declaring a fixed height on the card, and that the background will likely be required to be applied on the card itself opposed to the faces

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I took a look at it and made some tweaks as you can see on the jsFiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/nsUZB/1/

Mainly I removed the background-color and min-height on the flipper and set the lightBlue color on the front and back faces.

```
.flipper{
            //transform: perspective(1000px);
            transform-style: preserve-3d;
            position: relative;
            width: 100%;
            //min-height: 345px;
            transition: 0.6s;
            //background-color: rgb(242,245,245);
            box-shadow: 1px 2px 20px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6) inset, 1px 2px 5px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
        }


        .front, .back{
        backface-visibility: hidden;
        //transition: 0.6s;
        transform-style: preserve-3d;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        background: lightBlue;
    }
```

Let me know if this is going in the right direction.

Comment: this is the method to get the text to appear, by removing the background colour.

however, I was after an effect whereby the back of the element(back face) is to the same height (without declaring a fixed height).
so that it retains the effect of a card flipping over, as opposed to a card that is the height of the image, flipping over to a short card the size of the text.

these images may be different sizes, and the site will be fluid-responsive.

I could use JS on resize to set the height to the height of the flexible image, but I was looking at a pure css method.

ideas ?

Comment: Ah right.  Yeah I played around with it but I couldn't exactly find anything that would work without JS.  Even if I set the back or front to 100% height, they need something to base that off, which in this case would be their shared parent (.flipper).  So you might have to do something with JS.  Sorry.

Comment: Yeah it's going to have to be JS now to remain stable/more support.

it's just weird that my solution almost works, apart from the text flicking behind the background 99% of the time, and that 1% of the time it works perfectly. >.>!!

Comment: Just as an update to anyone reading this,
I have temporally resolved this by moving the background to the article above the flipper.
Removing the background from the flippers, and keeping the box-shadow on the flipper.
It still gives a slight impression of a card being flipped over. and I could always boost the box-shadow inset to spread across the entire inside (instead of using background-color)